# Adding area to mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an mvc project and I added a new area with the name BEK
and BEKAreaRegistration.cs was created.

```
public class BEKAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "BEK";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "BEK_default",
            "BEK/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and my global.asax file is as follows:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 

        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allAspx}", new { allAspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allAsmx}", new { allAsmx = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allAshx}", new { allAshx = @".*\.ashx(/.*)?" });
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Services/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("");

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

but when i try to go to BEK/Home/Index page I get an error page. What else should I do?

This is the error:

> The resource cannot be found.    Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /LMS_WEB_APP/BEK/Home
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18213

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that, You have **Same Name** controller in Both **Area** and and application. Like You have **Home Controller** in Normal Application and Also in **AREA**
And, it is causing the Duplicate Declaration of Same Controller.

The way doing that is, specifying the NAMESPACE of the Controller Like the Following :

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
    "BEK_default",
    "BEK/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    new string[] { "MyAppName.Areas.BEK.Controllers" }  // specify the new namespace
);
}
```

If not that Case, Please post the Error Message you are getting.

Comment: when i put breakpoint to this line it never hits that is the problem is not this

Comment: i did it sorry for the bad pasting

Comment: yes i have i did not do any extra thing. just add area by just right click to project --> add area. it adds home controller and views with folders

Comment: and also i do not have home view folder or controller in my app. i just have home folder in my area

Comment: Ok. So you have that Controller. Then, How do you calling that Area from your Application. Can you Show me your @html.actionLink() part?

Comment: Oh oh, You have only Home Folder in View. Then, pLease check that, Whether you have Home COntroller in AREA or not, and in View there is any Home Folder and an Index.cshtml.

Comment: So, There is no any View Regarding that Controller and Action. So, please add the View.

Comment: ok first of all i m adding area by right click to project and add area . so it creates everything you need for you.  i have no htmlactionLink i m just typing BEK/Home/Index to address bar

Comment: Please see the Second Solution i've posted.

Answer (score 0):

When you add BEK Area. 
MVC will create These for you.

[image]

Mvc will not create any Controller and Actions and Views.

So, you do have to do that manually that which controllers, actions and views you want to add.

So, now you do have to Add the Controller by Right Clicking on Controller and Add Controller.

After Adding the Controller.

You can do right click on the Action and Add View like this to add the View :

[image]

Ok....
So, you do have Both Controller and Action and Views required.

Now you might have to Resolve the Controller Duplicacy, if any, which i had told you earlier.

Happy Coading...